# Having issue opening Map via Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to open a map via Fragment and for some reason the app collapse instantly
I have also checked whether the API is correct and it seems to be ok.
I have checked online for solutions with no success.
in the MainActivity class i add only the line which makes the MapFragment object
thanks for the help

Manifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".gameActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GameOver"></activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCxgyRreLmjnrbHVQ9-Ka-_RS9gbTu_xLo" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

   <!-- <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@strings/google_map_api_key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />-->
    <!-- Location if you will use this -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

the call from MainActivity

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewside,new MapFragment()).commit();
```

---

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;
    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return  mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mMapView=(MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if(mMapView!=null)
        {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        LatLng sydney=new LatLng(30,30);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));
         mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }
}
```

The Xml relatet to the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Error Log

```
2019-01-06 22:09:28.462 28924-28924/? E/id.defcontaine: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.

    --------- beginning of system
2019-01-06 22:09:28.735 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-01-06 22:09:28.736 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-06 22:09:28.737 2462-26517/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
2019-01-06 22:09:28.738 2462-26517/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-06 22:09:28.738 2462-26517/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-06 22:09:28.740 2462-26517/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2019-01-06 22:09:28.742 2462-26517/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2019-01-06 22:09:28.801 1688-1907/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl262505887.tmp: No such file or directory
2019-01-06 22:09:28.954 28950-28950/? E/ndroid.keychai: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-01-06 22:09:30.426 1683-1707/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-01-06 22:09:30.572 1683-1955/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-01-06 22:09:33.390 29044-29044/? E/e.process.gapp: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-01-06 22:09:33.800 29010-29010/com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal, PID: 29010
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMapType(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.MapFragment.onMapReady(MapFragment.java:59)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzac.zza(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:31)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
        at fp.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):15)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):4)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-01-06 22:09:33.911 1838-1911/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'd10f057 com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal/com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-01-06 22:09:34.572 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-01-06 22:09:34.591 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-06 22:09:34.605 2462-29038/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
2019-01-06 22:09:34.606 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-06 22:09:34.606 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-06 22:09:34.607 2462-29038/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2019-01-06 22:09:34.615 2462-29038/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2019-01-06 22:09:34.677 1774-1774/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-01-06 22:09:34.677 1774-1774/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-01-06 22:09:34.847 2454-2454/? E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2019-01-06 22:09:34.919 2454-2454/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2019-01-06 22:09:35.320 2454-2995/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-01-06 22:09:37.602 2454-2936/? E/Volley: [130] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/getPlaceById?key=AIzaSyAf4nrRiEKvqzlRKTncQaAXMzb3ePYHr8Y
2019-01-06 22:09:37.613 2454-7936/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=GetPlaceById
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}]
        at bcmj.b(:com.google.android.gms@14799040@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3)
        at bcmc.a(:com.google.android.gms@14799040@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):29)
        at ybc.run(:com.google.android.gms@14799040@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):27)
        at beyi.run(:com.google.android.gms@14799040@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):2)
        at qwc.run(:com.google.android.gms@14799040@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at rbx.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-01-06 22:09:38.537 1696-1754/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-01-06 22:09:39.701 1593-2147/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-01-06 22:09:39.701 1593-2147/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-06 22:09:39.710 2462-29038/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
2019-01-06 22:09:39.710 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-06 22:09:39.712 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-06 22:09:39.712 2462-29038/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2019-01-06 22:09:39.714 2462-29038/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2019-01-06 22:09:41.401 1838-1852/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-01-06 22:09:43.411 1838-1852/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-01-06 22:09:44.757 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2019-01-06 22:09:44.757 1593-11870/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-06 22:09:44.763 2462-29038/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
2019-01-06 22:09:44.763 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-06 22:09:44.763 2462-29038/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-06 22:09:44.764 2462-29038/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

Comment: I think mGoogleMap is null in onMapReady method, I think first set mGoogleMap = googleMap;

Comment: Share your logcat so i can help you track the problem

Comment: just did @TamirAbutbul

Comment: I wrote you an answer , have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "mGoogleMap" variable is null , follow this code to fix it :

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap= googleMap;
    //inside onMapReady give your "mGoogleMap" value and call mapConfig 
    mapConfig(googleMap);
}

  private void mapConfig(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //this is a method for configuring your map(for clean code)
     googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));
     googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```